# How can I mount an .img file

Tags: macos, mount

I'm trying to do [this tutorial](https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi_Beginners_Guide), but I can't mount the img file:

```
sudo mount -o loop,offset=62914560 2015-05-05-raspbian-wheezy.img /mnt/rasp-pi-rootfs
```

It says `mount: You must specify a filesystem type with -t.`

How can I mount an image in OSX?

Comment: The tutorial is written for Linux, not OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you try to mount a linux file system `raspbian-wheezy.img` like ext2/3/4, xfs. OS X does not support these file systems. There's an [ext plugin for FUSE](http://osxdaily.com/2014/03/20/mount-ext-linux-file-system-mac/) which might enable you to add support for the file system you want.